# Dereferencing an iterator of a list of pointers

Tags: c++, iterator, operator-precedence

I have a problem trying to dereference an iterator of a `std::list<std::unique_ptr<MyClass>>`.
Here's my situation: in headerFile.h I have

```
class MyClass{
public:
   bool variable = false;
private:
};
```

and then in headerFile2.h

```
#include "headerFile.h"
#include <memory>
#include <list>
class OtherClass{
public:
private:
   std::list<std::unique_ptr<MyClass>> MyList;
   void MyFuction();
};
```

and, finally, in headerFile2.cpp I try to use MyClass::variable like this:

```
#include "headerFile2.h"
void OtherClass::MyFunction(){
   for(auto it = MyList.begin(); it != MyList.end(); it++){
      *it -> variable = true;
   }
}
```

It won't compile and I don't know where my mistake is. The error message is 
`'struct std::_List_iterator<std::unique_ptr<MyClass> >' has no member named 'variable'`

I also tried doing `**it.variable = true;`.

I would appreciate any advice.

Comment: [C++ operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence). `operator ->` has higher precedence than `operator*`. You need parantheses: `(*it)->variable`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`operator->` has higher [precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) than `operator*`, so `*it -> variable = true;` is interpreted as `*(it -> variable) = true;`, while `it -> variable` is invalid.

You can add parentheses as

```
(*it) -> variable = true;
```

`**it.variable = true;` has the similar issue; you could `(**it).variable = true;`.

Comment: That's it! Thank you very much :)